# How do you compare three lists and add the duplicates to one list and the non-duplicates to another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, concatenation

I need to devise a way to compare all of the numbers in the three lists and should a number be present in all three lists - I have to add it to the matching_numbers list. If a number doesn’t match any of the other numbers, then I have to add it to the unique_numbers list. I tried using a for loop, but I was only able to complete half of the equation and I wasn't sure as to how I could add all the unmatching numbers to the unique_numbers list. I also don't want any duplicates in my matching_numbers or unique_numbers list.

```
list_1 = []

list_2 = []

list_3 = []

matching_numbers = []

unique_numbers = []

countone = 0

counttwo = 0

countthree = 0

import random

name = input("Hello USER. What will your name be?")

print("Hello " + name + ". Welcome to the NUMBERS program.")

amountone = int(input("How many numbers do you wish to have for your first list? Please choose from between 1 and 15."))

while countone != amountone:
  x = random.randint(1, 50)
  list_1 += [x,]
  print(list_1)
  countone += 1

amounttwo = int(input("For your second list, how many numbers do you wish to have? Please choose from between 1 and 15."))

while counttwo != amounttwo:
  x = random.randint(1, 50)
  list_2 += [x,]
  print(list_2)
  counttwo += 1

amountthree = int(input("For your third list, how many numbers do you wish to have? Please choose from between 1 and 15."))

while countthree != amountthree:
  x = random.randint(1, 50)
  list_3 += [x,]
  print(list_3)
  countthree += 1

for a in list_1:
    for b in list_2:
        for c in list_3:
          if a == b and b == c:
            matching_numbers = list(set(list_1) & set(list_2) & set(list_3))
          else:
            unique_numbers =
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the type of thing that [`Sets`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) are perfect for. Unlike a list, where checking if something is present has a compexity of `O(n)`, set lookups are `O(1)`. Also, sets have methods already to check for intersections, differences, etc. So items in three sets can be computed as the intersection of the three:

```
all_numbers = set_1 | set_2 | set_3
matching_numbers = set_1 & set_2 & set_3
unique_numbers = all_numbers - matching_numbers
```

Comment: This doesn't find unique numbers among three sets. Consider three set_1: {7}, set_2: {9}, set_3: {7}. `matching_numbers` will be empty and  `unique_numbers` will be `{7, 9}` which is not correct since 7 is in two sets.

Comment: The OP's requirements don't say how duplicates should be handled; I think a set implementation is more correct, but who knows what's being asked for.

Comment: I guess I read `If a number doesn’t match any of the other numbers, then I have to add it to the unique_numbers list.` To mean the numbers in `unique_numbers` would be globally unique.